# Why does GNU Find care about a trailing slash in this situation?

Tags: unix, find, gnu, gnu-coreutils

Given:

- I am running GNU/Linux
- I have some Git repositories in `/path/to/repos`.
- I want to check whether any files in the `myrepo` repository were modified after a particular time.
- `find /path/to/repos/myrepo -type l` prints no results, showing that `myrepo`'s directory structure contains no symlinks.
- The directory `/path/to/repos/myrepo/.git` has a modification time more recent than the one I'm interested in, but no other files in `myrepo` or any of its subdirectories do.

When I enter the following command, I see no results:

`find /path/to/repos/myrepo -name .git -prune -o -path '/path/to/repos/myrepo/*' -newermt '2020-05-18 15:52:34' -print`

Yet when I add a trailing slash to the starting point,

`find /path/to/repos/myrepo/ -name .git -prune -o -path '/path/to/repos/myrepo/*' -newermt '2020-05-18 15:52:34' -print`

the command prints `/path/to/repos/myrepo/`.

Why this difference?

Answer (score 3):

GNU Find preserves the starting-point as entered, so in the first example, `/path/to/repos/myrepo` doesn't match `-path '/path/to/repos/myrepo/*'` because the path expression includes a trailing slash and there is no trailing slash in the directory name.

In the second example, since the directory name does include a trailing slash, it successfully matches the path expression `/path/to/repos/myrepo/*`.

The `-newermt` test is irrelevant here. Note that the other paths processed by `find` in these examples are identical, regardless of whether the starting-point contained a trailing slash. I.e., if `myrepo` contains a file `xyz`, it is processed as `/path/to/repos/myrepo/xyz` in both cases. In other words, for subpaths of the starting-point, a trailing slash is appended to the starting-point if needed; this just doesn't apply to the starting-point itself.